# jenssegers/mongodb migrations for creating unique index on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I need to create a Laravel migration for a unique key on multiple fields.
The Mongodb command i want to map is something like this:

> db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true })

Is it possible with jenssegers/mongodb or with another package?

Answer (score 4):

```
Schema::create('collection', function ( $collection ) {
      $collection->unique(array( 'a', 'b' ));
});
```